# when I import aar file in my project, it creashes

Tags: android, android-studio

First, I create a new default project and in the created project I right click on the project and I choose the `New Module` and then I see a window that it has difference options. I choose the `Android library` and then I create a class in the created new library and then I go to `project structure` and using the dependencies tab I create `aar` file from the new library. And then I close the all of the project and I create a new default project and I copy the `aar` file in the `lib` folder in the new default project and then I go to the project folder and I choose the `Module` and then I see a window that it has difference options and I choose the `JAR/AAR packages` option and then I go to this new default project and I choose the `aar` file that I copied it in that. But at this moment, importing the `aar` file is not successfully and I can not see errors in the window and for this reason  I do not know that the origin of the problem.

Comment: If the app crashes post the stacktrace.